# Finding the index of the items that is currently visible to the user in list view in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, imagelist

I'm using a list view control attached to an image list.I want to obtain the indexes of the items that are currently seen by the user ie:in user view so that i can load the corresponding images only neglecting the images for the items out of user view.
Please Help me out.

Comment: Can you post some code showing what you've tried already?

Comment: This is very vague and a code snippet would go a long way...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your list's "View" property is set to 'Details' or 'List' you can use the .TopItem property to find the first visible item in the list.  From your control geometry you should then be able to figure how many items beyond that you need to draw.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.topitem.aspx